# Soultion of a particular functional differential equation

Tags: functional-equations

I need to solve the following functional differential equation:

$(4\mu-\lambda r - \lambda x+\lambda)f'(x) = \lambda( f(x) - f(1-x-r))$, where $x\in (0, 1-r)$, $r\in (\frac{1}{2}, 1)$

Or, a more general version of it.
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: You need an analytic solution? Or a numerical method is OK? Where did this come from?

Comment: No, a numerical solution will not do. I need an analytical one, i.e. an expression for f(x). This comes as a side problem in my research.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Write $f(x) = g(t) + h(t)$ where
$$ \eqalign{t &= x - (1-r)/2\cr
             g(t) &= (f(x) + f(1-r-x))/2\cr
             h(t) &= (f(x) - f(1-r-x))/2\cr}$$
Thus $g$ is an even function and $h$ is an odd function.
Your equation becomes
$$ (4\mu + \lambda(1-r)/2 - \lambda t) (g'(t) + h'(t)) = 2 \lambda h(t) $$
For convenience, let $A = 4 \mu/\lambda + (1-r)/2$, so this says
$$ (A - t)(g'(t) + h'(t)) = 2 h(t)$$
Changing $t$ to $-t$ (and remembering that $g'$ is odd and $h'$ is even) we get
$$ (A + t)(-g'(t) + h'(t)) = -2 h(t) $$
We can then solve for $g'$ and $h'$, obtaining 
$$\eqalign{g'(t) &= \dfrac{2 A \; h(t)}{A^2 - t^2}\cr
h'(t) &= \dfrac{2 t\; h(t)}{A^2 - t^2}}$$
But since $h$ is odd, we need $h(0) = 0$
and then the solution of this initial value problem for $h$ is 
$h(t) = 0$.  Integrating the other equation, $g(t)$ is constant.
So you get the rather uninteresting (but obvious, on hindsight!) solutions
$$f(x) = constant$$